# Delphi 11.2 Patch 1 frames and High-DPI

Tags: delphi, highdpi

I have encountered a problem with Delphi's multi monitor high-DPI support that I would welcome any insights you might have. I am using Delphi 11.2 patch 1 on a 5K monitor with Delphi's form designed set to Automatic (Screen PPI)

I have a small test project with a TDBAdvGrid and a TDBNavigator at the top of the form and a separate Tframe at the bottom of that form added at design time also having a TDBNavigator and a TDBAdvGrid on it. When I run the program initially it all looks fine.

[image: Main Monitor @ 5K]

As I said,I am designing on a 5K monitor (5120x2880) at 200% font scaling and I have a second monitor attached (1920x1080) at 100% font scaling.   If I drag the form onto the second monitor the grid and navigator on the form appear to respond nearly as they should (just doesn't get the column widths quite correct) but the grid and the navigator in the TFrame don't.

[image: Second monitor]

Then if I drag the form back to the main monitor the TFrame is even more messed up
[image: Back to the main monitor]

Do you have any recommendations on how to handle this?  Should I be doing something with the main form's onBefore/OnAfterMonitorDPIChange events?

This high-DPI stuff all seems very much work in progress.  And if I wanted to persist the column widths in an ini file, how would that work?  Would I have to save it separately for each monitors PPI settings?

Comment: "This high-DPI stuff all seems very much work in progress. And if I wanted to persist the column widths in an ini file, how would that work? Would I have to save it separately for each monitors PPI settings?" Couple of options. Convert to 100% and save that, then convert from 100% when restoring from ini file. Or save the current PPI alongside the widths, and again scale when restoring. The former might play better with old versions of your software that didn't support per monitor PPI.

Comment: I mentioned the problem with the column widths in the TDBAdvGrid to TMS Software who develop that component and they say they have released a fix for it. https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsvcluipack.asp?s=history Full marks to them for such a speedy response!